# Limit access to an EC2 instance from different instances

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance set up called `Machine1`. I specified the security group to be `Group1`. How can I allow access in `Group1` to any machine that comes from an internal EC2 request? Do I have the specify the IP address of each machine?

Answer (score 1):

Machines from the same security group can acces other machine in the same security group (by default). Usually this is the topmost rule in the INBOUND rules table like:

```
ALL sg-xxxxxxx (default) Delete
```

You can add like this other security groups to the rules, just check out the other groups `sg-xxxxxx` id on it's Details tab and then add it as the new rules source.